# Display 3 variables out of 7 based on their value

Tags: php

I have the following variables:

```
$points_maxbet = 0;
$points_netbet = 0;
$points_888 = 0;
$points_sportingbet = 0;
$points_betano = 0;
$points_unibet = 0;
$points_betfair = 0;
```

During the execution of the script their values get incremented by different values.

Example:

```
if ((mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_01'])) == 'A')
{
    $points_maxbet += 5;
    $points_netbet += 5;
    $points_888 += 5;
    $points_sportingbet += 5;
    $points_betano += 5;
    $points_unibet += 5;
    $points_betfair += 5;
}
```

After they pass trough all of the increments I want to display just 3 out of those 7 variables (based on their highest values) and display some HTML for each of them.

I tried something but it would only give me the highest value variable, not the following 2 as well.

Looked for a solution on SO and Google but couldn't find any.

Let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, put them in an array at the end, sort them and pick off the top 3 elements. Sort of like the following:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        'maxbet' => $points_maxbet,
        'netbet' => $points_netbet,
        'eighteighteight' => $points_eighteighteight,
        'sportingbet' => $points_sportingbet,
        'betano' => $points_betano,
        'unibet' => $points_unibet,
        'betfair' => $points_betfair);
    asort($array);
    $top3 = array_slice($array, -3);
?>
```

Using this in html could be as simple as something like this (code not tested yet):

```
<ol>
<?php foreach($top3 as $key => $value): ?>
    <li><?php echo $key; ?> - <?php echo $value; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Looks like a familiar response?

Comment: use of `arsort` then `array_reverse` is pointless when `asort` would do this anyway.

Comment: @Luke see the updated answer... I think the question warrants you know which values are there in the end... The resulting array makes sure you still have the names of the variables in the end!

Comment: @RichardBernards It does work, however the order it displays the values is something like this:
    netbet - 57
    unibet - 58
    maxbet - 64
I need them in reverse order, the highest value being the first. :)

Comment: Since you've swapped to `asort` you'll need to `slice` with a negative offset `array_slice($array, -3, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Put them into an array and use `asort` to order the array lowest->highest then `pop` off the last `3`

```
$arr = [$maxbet, $netbet, $eighteighteight, $sportingbet, $betano, $unibet, $betfair];

asort($arr);

$first = array_pop($arr);
$second = array_pop($arr);
$third = array_pop($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way I solve the first problem, sorting them. How can I proceed to the last part now (display some HTML for each of them)? The HTML would be dependent on the variable's name, having a unique HTML for each variable. This way I get just the values in the array, but not their names, right?

Comment: I'd update to `$key => $value` array and then add a switch statement or if statement to generate the HTML

Comment: @SporeDev see @RichardBernards final answer. but just use `asort` rather than `arsort` and `array_reverse`

Comment: his updated answer uses asort as well. It's just that I get the results ordered from lowest to highest instead of the other way around.

Comment: use `array_slice($array, -3, 3);` to take from the end of the array.

Comment: It's ok now, I changed it to array_slice($array, 0, 3); and it works as intended. Thank you very much!